# QTreeView checkbox color

Tags: qt5, qtreeview, qcheckbox

I'm trying to add color to the checkboxes in a `QTreeView`, like so

[image: Colored checkboxes]

I switched from a `QStyledItemDelegate` to a `QItemDelegate` to have a better control on the drawing process, mostly for the [`drawCheck`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#drawCheck) method. I can't get the painter to draw the colors I want though. Using css, I succeeded in changing the color of all checkboxes, but I need to choose the colors depending on some properties (unimportant here). Modifying the QStyle of the QTreeView may work but I will have the same "unique color" problem.

Modifying the painter or the option parameters do nothing.

```
painter->setPen(aRandomColor);
auto coloredOption = option;
coloredOption.backgroundBrush.setColor(aRandomColor);
QItemDelegate::drawCheck(painter, coloredOption, rect, state);
```

I understand that I can handle the complete drawing process in my own `drawCheck` without calling `QItemDelegate::drawCheck`

```
const auto color = wathever;
draw square outline using color
draw filled square using color
// Do NOT call QItemDelegate::drawCheck(...)
```

but this will force an uniform feel on all OSes. Is there no way to ask for a background color? Like... paint what you were going to paint, but do it using {color}"?

Comment: Please, provide your implementation of the delegate

Comment: There's no need. My `QItemDelegate` is uselessly complex because I also draw icons. There's no interesting part in it relating to this question. Only a empty `drawCheck` implementation where I tested my ideas. I know it works because I was able to change the checkbox state.

Comment: It would be more efficient ifI could copy and paste your code. The time I'll spend to setup a whole new project could be used for other questions

Comment: You could try setting the `palette` member of `coloredOption` rather than setting the `backgroundBrush`.property.  Just guessing.

Comment: @G.M. There's no `palette` member in `QStyleOptionViewItem`. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's a member of the [`QStyleOption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoption.html#palette-var) base class.

Comment: I set the colors of the palette with all `QPalette::ColorRole` to `Qt::red` and it's doing nothing. It looks like it's not used when drawing the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested all the members I could find, to no avail. So I did what I didn't want to do: handle the drawing process myself.

```
void ActionsItemDelegate::drawCheck(QPainter *painter, ...) {
    if (thisCheckboxNeedsColoring) {
        painter->setPen(dynamicColor);
#ifdef __APPLE__
        painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        QPainterPath path;
        path.addRoundedRect(QRectF(rect.adjusted(3, 3, -4, -3)), 1.0, 1.0);
        painter->fillPath(path, color);
        painter->drawPath(path);
        if (state != Qt::Unchecked)
        {
          painter->fillRect(rect.adjusted(5, 8, -6, -8), Qt::white);
        }
#else
        painter->drawRect(rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1));
        if (state != Qt::Unchecked)
        {
          painter->fillRect(rect.adjusted(3, 3, -3, -3), color);
        }
#endif
    } else {
        QItemDelegate::drawCheck(painter, option, rect, state);
    }
}
```

Of course, this doesn't take into account the styles or themes that Windows, Linux and macOS provide. I have no solution to this problem. I'm still open to better solutions!